# Replace multiples of 3's in a list with an X

Tags: python

Q: Use a for loop and range function to replace multiples of 3's in a list with an X, where N is an integer supplied from stdin.

My lousy attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

strings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

new_strings = []

for string in strings:
    new_string = string.replace("3", "X")

    new_strings.append(new_string)

print(new_strings)
```

My output:

```
['1', '2', 'X', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

The output should be:

```
['1', '2', 'X', '4', '5', 'X', '7', '8']
```

Basically, any multiple of 3 should be replaced with an X. How do I do this??

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I edited it just there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list elements can be converted to an int then you can use list comprehension as:

```
x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
x = [elt if int(elt)%3 != 0 else "X" for elt in x]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', 'X', '4', '5', 'X', '7', '8']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is visually the best solution:

```py
strings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

new_strings = []

for string in strings:
    if int(string) % 3 == 0:
        new_string = "X"
    else:
        new_string = string
    new_strings.append(new_string)

print(new_strings)
```

Basically what is happening here is that the if statement checks if the value from the array is divisible by 3 without any remainder - the `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> list(map(lambda i: 'X' if int(i)%3 == 0 else i, x)) 

['1', '2', 'X', '4', '5', 'X', '7', '8']
```